Your request of 5143.88 meters per pixel exceeds the limit 1500.00 meters per pixel of the collection S2L2A. Please revise the resolution
I am getting the error . I am using sentinelapi to download images from sentinel 2 l2a .The user draws polygons in the frontend from the map. (it is using leaflet). I am getting the error and I don't know how to solve this.
Your request of 5143.88 meters per pixel exceeds the limit 1500.00 meters per pixel of the collection S2L2A. Please revise the resolution (or corresponding width/height) to make sure it is in supported range

here is the code that is causing the issue
def get_sentinel_images(field_polygon, start_date, end_date, cloud_cover, selected_area):
    area_in_meters =selected_area 
    

    
    
    # configuration
    config = get_config()


    # search for the catalogue
    geometry = Geometry(geometry=field_polygon, crs=CRS.WGS84)
    time_interval = start_date, end_date


    catalog = SentinelHubCatalog(config=config)

    search_iterator = catalog.search(
        DataCollection.SENTINEL2_L2A,
        
        time=time_interval,
        filter="eo:cloud_cover < {}".format(cloud_cover),
        fields={"include": ["id", "properties.datetime", "properties.eo:cloud_cover"], "exclude": []},
        geometry=geometry,
        
    )

    results = list(search_iterator)
    print("Total number of results:", len(results))


    # separating the unique acquisitions

    time_difference = dt.timedelta(hours=0)

    all_timestamps = search_iterator.get_timestamps()
    unique_acquisitions = filter_times(all_timestamps, time_difference)

    print("Total number of unique acquisitions:", len(unique_acquisitions))

    # make a request to process API for these acquisitions
    true_color_evalscript = """
    //VERSION=3
    function setup() {
    return {
        input: ["B02", "B03", "B04"],
        output: {
        bands: 3,
        sampleType: "AUTO", // default value - scales the output values from [0,1] to [0,255].
        },
    }
    }

    function evaluatePixel(sample) {
        return [2.5 * sample.B04, 2.5 * sample.B03, 2.5 * sample.B02]
    }
    """

    nvdi_evalscript =  """
//VERSION=3
function setup() {
  return {
    input: [
      {
        bands: ["B04", "B08"],
      },
    ],
    output: {
      id: "default",
      bands: 3,
    },
  }
}

function evaluatePixel(sample) {
  let ndvi = (sample.B08 - sample.B04) / (sample.B08 + sample.B04)

  if (ndvi < -0.5) return [0.05, 0.05, 0.05]
  else if (ndvi < -0.2) return [0.75, 0.75, 0.75]
  else if (ndvi < -0.1) return [0.86, 0.86, 0.86]
  else if (ndvi < 0) return [0.92, 0.92, 0.92]
  else if (ndvi < 0.025) return [1, 0.98, 0.8]
  else if (ndvi < 0.05) return [0.93, 0.91, 0.71]
  else if (ndvi < 0.075) return [0.87, 0.85, 0.61]
  else if (ndvi < 0.1) return [0.8, 0.78, 0.51]
  else if (ndvi < 0.125) return [0.74, 0.72, 0.42]
  else if (ndvi < 0.15) return [0.69, 0.76, 0.38]
  else if (ndvi < 0.175) return [0.64, 0.8, 0.35]
  else if (ndvi < 0.2) return [0.57, 0.75, 0.32]
  else if (ndvi < 0.25) return [0.5, 0.7, 0.28]
  else if (ndvi < 0.3) return [0.44, 0.64, 0.25]
  else if (ndvi < 0.35) return [0.38, 0.59, 0.21]
  else if (ndvi < 0.4) return [0.31, 0.54, 0.18]
  else if (ndvi < 0.45) return [0.25, 0.49, 0.14]
  else if (ndvi < 0.5) return [0.19, 0.43, 0.11]
  else if (ndvi < 0.55) return [0.13, 0.38, 0.07]
  else if (ndvi < 0.6) return [0.06, 0.33, 0.04]
  else return [0, 0.27, 0]
}
"""
    nvdi_process_requests = []
    process_requests = []
    
  
    for timestamp in unique_acquisitions:
        request = SentinelHubRequest(
            evalscript=true_color_evalscript,
          
            input_data=[
                SentinelHubRequest.input_data(
                    data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL2_L2A.define_from("s2l2a", service_url=config.sh_base_url),
                    time_interval=(timestamp - time_difference, timestamp + time_difference),
                )
            ],
            responses=[SentinelHubRequest.output_response("default", MimeType.PNG)],
            geometry=geometry,
            
           
            config=config,

        )
        
        
        process_requests.append((request,timestamp))

    print("requesting nvdi images ...")
    # repeating the request but for nvdi images
    for timestamp in unique_acquisitions:
        request = SentinelHubRequest(
            data_folder='data_folder',
            evalscript=nvdi_evalscript,
            input_data=[
                SentinelHubRequest.input_data(
                    data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL2_L2A.define_from("s2l2a", service_url=config.sh_base_url),
                    time_interval=(timestamp - time_difference, timestamp + time_difference),
                )
            ],
            responses=[SentinelHubRequest.output_response("default", MimeType.TIFF)],
           
            
            geometry=geometry,
            config=config,
)
        nvdi_process_requests.append(request)
        
    
    

    # download the data 
    client = SentinelHubDownloadClient(config=config)
    download_requests = [request.download_list[0] for request,_ in process_requests]
    timestamps = [timestamps for request,timestamps in process_requests]
    data = client.download(download_requests)
    images = convert_ndarray_to_base64(data)
    
    
    images_with_timestamps=list(map(list,zip(images,timestamps)))
    # arranging the list into descending order(from most recent to oldest)
    images_with_timestamps.reverse()
    nvdi_process_requests.reverse()
    
    
    return images_with_timestamps, nvdi_process_requests

What I have done?
I tried adding the size parameter in request class conditionally . This somehow removes the error but I did not get the image with the resolution of 10m per pixels . Like this
 desired_resolution = 10
 max_size_in_pixels = 2500
 size_in_pixels = int(min(area_in_meters / desired_resolution, max_size_in_pixels))

...
request = SentinelHubRequest(
            evalscript=true_color_evalscript,
          
            input_data=[
                SentinelHubRequest.input_data(
                    data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL2_L2A.define_from("s2l2a", service_url=config.sh_base_url),
                    time_interval=(timestamp - time_difference, timestamp + time_difference),
                )
            ],
            responses=[SentinelHubRequest.output_response("default", MimeType.PNG)],
            geometry=geometry,
            size=(size_in_pixels, size_in_pixels),
           
            config=config,

        )


I want to get the images with base resolution of 10 m per pixels . It has been many days I have stuck into this problem. Thanks
